# Why does follower count greater than 0 cause stack level too deep?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a relationships model (for following and followers) and my project is also aimed at providing an api. Now there is a profile api that sends out the name, username, amount of followers and following. If I send a get request to my channel controller then I get the name, username and the followers and following as `[]`. If someone follows the user I get a "stack level too deep" in console. I have no idea what the cause to this could be and how I could fix this? Any thoughts?

Also, here is some more info:

**show.json.jbuilder** (my json show page)

```
json.call(
@user,
:username,
:name,
:following,
:followers
)
```

**profiles_controller.rb**

```
class API::V1::ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, only: [:show]
  respond_to :json

  def show
    @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount API::Base, at: "/"
  resources :relationships
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resource :sessions, only: [:create, :destroy]
      resources :registrations
      resources :profiles do
        member do
          get :following, :followers
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The follower and following amount works on the html webpage and I can also follow other people through the html webpage. It seems as the issue is in the json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare the content for following/followers in jbuilder

```
json.call @user, :username, :name
json.following @user.following, :username, :name
json.followers @user.followers, :username, :name
```